# How to connect React Native Expo app to Facebook Ads?

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I am trying to run facebook ads for my newly released app (ForeFriends). I want the ads to optimize for app installs. In order to do this I have to [connect my app to facebook](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/303269370149084). It's, of course, very complicated and assumes I'm not using react native. I've looked on the expo website and there's nothing. I've also watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEXMVTVdsrw&t=838s) but it's not totally clear on how to do it and the links in his description don't even exist anymore. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks.